# C++ auto in static_cast

Tags: c++, casting, auto

The `auto` keyword can be used in many contexts and combined with other language elements, as in `const auto&` or `auto&&`. However, it cannot be used in cast operations. Consider the following example (which does not compile):

```cpp
template <class T> void foo(T&& t) {}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    foo(static_cast<const auto&>(i)); // This could call foo(const int&)
}
```

The cast would obviously work with `int` instead of `auto`, but being able to use `auto` in casts would be useful in generic code, for instance:

- You could use `const auto&` (as above) to explicitly call an overloaded function with a const lvalue ref.
- Similarly, you could use `static_cast<auto&&>` as a less verbose version of `std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)`.
- Thinking a bit further, `static_cast<auto>(x)` or something like `auto(x)` could be a way of explicitly copying an object.

**(Note that explicit types instead of `auto` can be used in all these scenarios.)**

To be honest, I intuitively expected this syntax to work (because it mirrors the way `auto` can be used in declarations), but to my mild surprise it didn't. Since it is such an obvious syntax, I am wondering whether there are specific reasons why it is disallowed? Or is it simply a case of nobody considering/proposing it as a feature?

Comment: `auto` is used in declarations, not in expressions. That is why `auto` works for things like `auto i = 0;`, but not for things like `static_cast<const auto&>(i)`

Comment: I can kind of see how `static_cast<const auto&>` would be nice, but it is not needed.  You can just use [`std::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const).  Your last example can use `decltype(x)(x)` instead to get a copy.

Comment: I would expect the behaviour of `static_cast<auto&&>(x)` to depend only on the expression `x`, not the declaration of `x`. So I don't think it would be a good idea for it to do something like `std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)`.

Comment: @SergeyA To my knowledge that is a very common way and is often used as a macro definition, see countless SE/SO posts. If you want to forward an expression, you can use `static_cast<decltype(x)&&>(x)`, which is even worse.

Comment: @NathanOliver It is true that all these example uses can be achieved by other means. But on the other hand, shouldn't `auto` be consistent with regular types?

Comment: Well, `auto` isn't a regular type, it's a place holder, like `T` in a template.  It needs to be initialized with something to get a type.  In `static_cast<const auto&>`, the `<const auto&>` part expects a type, but you can't have one since `auto` by itself is not a type.  It might be possible to adapt the language to get this to work but you would need to submit a paper and work out all of the mechanics of how the new way would work and how it won't break what already exists (C++ really likes its backwards compatibility).

Comment: @NathanOliver I kind of felt that there is probably a rationale as to why this wasn't allowed in the first place, seeing how it is so similar to `const auto& ii = i;`

Comment: @SergeyA Sorry but did you read my reply? I said that my original version is widely used as a macro definition (which it is), and that `static_cast<decltype(x)&&>(x)` *can* be used instead.

Comment: @DanielS this is true. I will remove my comments.

Comment: `auto(x)` is actually in C++23 (see P0849R8), although it may not do exactly what you would expect it to do.